# Как сделать сайт по центру?

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Есть следующий код, как сделать четко по центру весь сайт, не используя при этом <center> и таблицу

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Ельцовка</title><meta charset=UTF-8><style> body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: font } @font-face { font-family: font; src: url(font.ttf) } header { white-space: nowrap; margin-top: 20px } .nl{ color: #111; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; padding:2px 7px } article { text-align: justify; width: 350px } .b { width: 400px; } </style></head><body><div class=b><header><h1>Развлекательно новостной сайт села Ельцовки</h1></header><nav><a class=nl href=index.html>Домой</a><a class=nl href=photoendvideo.html>Фото & Видео</a><a class=nl href=news.html>Новости</a></nav><section><article><h1>Заголовок главной статьи</h1><p>В этом блоке будет располагаться главная новость дня, недели, месяца или года. Она должно вмещаться в блог и нести самое главное основной новости. Открывая новость, читатель должен будет узнать только подробности.</p></article>    </section><footer><p>Шнайдер Владимир</p></footer></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Развлекательно-новостной - по моему нужно через тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я так понимаю, что `div.b` это контейнер всей страницы? для него задайте `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Получается что содержимое тега header не по центру, а все остальное по центру

Comment: Нужно что бы header был по центру а все остальное было по левому краю от header

Comment: вы добавляете этот стиль для контейнера всей страницы. по центру выравнивается он.

Comment: ну а вопрос как звучит?

Comment: .b { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }
это я прописываю в стилях
получается что расстояние до начало header больше чем расстояние от правого края экрана до конца header

Comment: это у Вас происходит из-за того, что `h1` в заголовке явно шире `400px`. остальная часть контента находится по центру. посмотрите что получится, если задать `overflow: hidden` для этого `h1`

ПС хотелось бы ещё попросить проявлять уважение к людям, к которым Вы обращаетесь за помощью, и не писать больше код в одну строку. у меня нет вычислительного ядра, чтобы понимать эту цепочку символов.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот это Вам нужно?](http://jsfiddle.net/DhyaK/)